# Jsoup URL.get()/post() out of memory error

Tags: java, android, html, http, jsoup

I'm executing this code:

```
            //doc = Jsoup.connect(data[0].getURL()).get();
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).post();
```

and am getting an out of memory exception.  Obviously the web page's HTML is too much too download.  All I want from the webpage are all of the elements within the following tags

```
<div class="animal-info">...</div>
```

Is there a way for me to do this using Jsoup without having to download the whole webpage, or a way to get around the out of memory exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();



 Elements divElements = doc.getElementsByTag("div");
         for(Element divElement : divElements){
             if(divElement.attr("class").equals("animal-info")){
                 textList.add(divElement.text());

                text = textList.toString();
                Log.e("Content", text);

             }
```

Comment: Looks like it worked, thanks a lot!  How come my way got the out of memory exception?  Is it a difference between post and get?  I also did Elements elements = doc.getElementsByClass("animal-info");

Comment: Yes it is a different between Post and get. Get is actually getting or retrieving the HTML. Post isnt. It is used for something different than actually getting the HTML to parse it. And glad it worked. I rely on jsoup alot. It is a wonderful parser